# Numpy correlation co-efficient for similar numbers

Tags: numpy

```
T = array([1, 1, 1, 1,1]) P = array([2.0, 8.7, 4.7, 8.2,9.7]) print corrcoef([T,P])
```

gives an error

> [ [nan nan nan 1.]] invalid value encountered in divide return c/sqrt(multiply.outer(d,d))

Since the values in `T` are same but if I give different value it works. But my requirement is an output for the above data

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the correlation isn't defined since the variance of `T` is zero. You could consider using covariance instead of correlation:

```
In [8]: cov([T, P])
Out[8]: 
array([[  0.   ,   0.   ],
       [  0.   ,  10.333]])
```